# Сохранение данных рядов ячеек objective C (Xcode)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Всем доброго дня. Есть у меня таблица с ячейкой. В каждом ряду ячейки есть кнопка (Button), принимающая значение включено-выключено (да-нет).

Вот так реализован метод кнопки на включение

```
UIImage *checkSel = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if (sender == 0) {
        [self.checkButton setBackgroundImage:checkSel forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        checkReq0 = YES;
        self.checkLabel.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"boolCheck0"];
        }
```

На выключение аналогично.

Теперь в чем вопрос:

При скролле ряды ячейки, выходящие из области экрана отгружаются, как и должно быть, а значит и теряются значения кнопки. То есть, нажал я на кнопку, галочку скажем поставил (значение YES), пролистываю вниз, чтобы из поля зрения эта кнопка исчезла, потом наоборот пролистываю вверх до появления этой кнопки и ее значение уже NO, дефолтное (то есть галочка снята).

Как сделать так, чтобы при отгрузке ряда, кнопка оставалась включенной? 
Я в голове переваривал 2 варианта: либо как то отключать отгрузку рядов из памяти, что не очень хорошо при большом количестве рядов (если это вообще возможно), либо же при каждом нажатии принимать новое стандартное значение через NSUserDefaults, что я попытался сделать в коде выше, но оно почему-то не работает.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше поступить?

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно создать коллекцию в которой будете хранить отмеченные ячейки.
Можно использовать `NSMutableSet` в котором можно хранить индексы ячеек у которых кнопка включена и при перезагрузке ячеек проверяйте индекс в `NSMutableSet` и при нахождении индекса в `NSMutableSet` отмечать кнопку включенной или что-то еще.